# Avoiding Nested Lists

Tags: python

What is the most Pythonic way to print the first element of each of the lists?

For example, I want `['apple', 'banana']` from the list of lists below:

```
data = [['apple','airplane'],['banana','boat']]
```

This is my best attempt:

```
fruit = [list(fruit) for fruit in data]

[letter[0] for letter in fruit]
```

However, having two list comprehensions doesn't seems very pythonic

Comment: well, the first list comprehension doesn't change anything: `[['apple','airplane'],['banana','boat']] == [list(fruit) for fruit in [['apple','airplane'],['banana','boat']]]` results in `True`...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
fruit = [fruit[0] for fruit in data]
```

That gets me the expected output, see below:

```
>>> data = [['apple','airplane'],['banana','boat']]
>>> fruit = [fruit[0] for fruit in data]
>>> print fruit
['apple', 'banana']
```